# In App Purchase Tab Cannot possible to access

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5, in-app-purchase

I have developed iphone app with working In App Purchase. Now I want to release new version of the app with new price for in App Purchase. But, Whenever I tapped on iTunesConnect -> Manage Your Applications-> My App -> Manage In App Purchase, I found this ------"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Seventeen".

Can anybody tell me, how to tackle with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that there's no solution for that. It is a bug on Apple's side. This iTunesConnect site stinks in all possible ways. I recommend you to fill a feature request asking Apple to provide a software application we can use to manage our apps and in-apps that are already created. Do it at http://bugreport.apple.com. I already did that and the bigger the number of people asking for it, more likely Apple will create that.